# grep With min Number of matches

Tags: awk, command-line, grep

How can I do a `grep -rli word dir` but only list files inside of dir that contain word at least x times?

Show all files that contain word 3 or more timesfor example

or 4 or more times

Comment: Please [edit] your question to define `word` for your purposes and show us concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you come up with the right solution. Make sure to include regexp meta-chars and potential partial matches in your example.

Comment: The word match is 3 times on one line or throughout the file? Those are two very different things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that your Input_file could have search word more than time 1 time in a single line and you want to count it per line's including multiple occurrence. I would go with `find` + `awk` solution here.

Lets create `awk` code file first:

```
cat count.awk
{
  sum+=gsub(var,"&")
}
END{
  if(sum>=count){
    print FILENAME
  }
}
```

***Then following command could be run:*** Where `var` is the variable which needs to be searched and `count` is variable which has the number of times at least that word would have come in that file.

```
find -type f -exec awk -v var="bla" -v count="3" -f count.awk {} \;
```

---

---

***Testing for above:***

- Let's create 3 files as follows for testing purposes.

```
cat file1
bla bla bla
test test test

cat file2
bla bla bla
test test test

cat file4
bla
test test test
```

- Now when we run the following:

```
find -type f -exec awk -v var="bla" -v count="3" -f count.awk {} \;
./file2
./file1
```

***NOTE:*** In case word occurence you are looking throughout the Input_file then change `gsub` to `sub` in above `awk` solution and it will catch 1 word per line only.

Comment: How do I make it case insensitive? Prepending `IGNORECASE=1;` to the start of `count.awk` prints every single input file's contents

Comment: @minseong, try like `find -type f -exec awk -v var="bla" -v IGNORECASE="1" -v count="3" -f count.awk {} \;` I tested it and it is working perfectly fine, please do let me know in case of any more queries, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that occurrences are on separate lines, you can use `grep -c` (which counts matching lines).

The output looks like `<file>:<count>`:

```
$ grep -c 'word' *
file1:0
file2:7
file3:2
```

assuming that we already are in the directory containing the files we're interested in. To get the names of files with more than a certain number of occurrences, we can use awk:

```
$ grep -c func * | awk -F: -v n=3 '$2 >= n { print $1 }'
file2
```

where `3` is the minimum number of occurrences required.

---

Limitations:

- Counts multiple words on the same line as a single match
- Expects there to be no newlines in filenames; `grep -Z` would enable separation with a zero byte, and awk could use that instead of `:`
- If the `*` glob expands to a list including directories, grep prints an error message for each